# How to convert NSURL to CFURL in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the code I am running in the Swift playground:

```
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox

var audioURL:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("/path")

var audioFile:UnsafePointer<AudioFileID>

var audioCfUrl:CFURL = audioURL as CFURL

AudioFileOpenURL(audioCfUrl!, Int8(kAudioFileReadPermission), 0, &audioFile)
```

On the last line I am getting the error:

```
'NSURL' is not a subtype of CFURL
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you give a complete self-contained example, including the call to AudioFileOpenURL() ?

Comment: Are you on the latest beta? It doesn't look like anyone's getting that specific error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message might be misleading.

- `audioCfUrl!` is wrong because `audioCfUrl` is not an optional.
- The last argument should be the address of an `AudioFileID` variable.

As already said in a (now deleted) answer, you don't have to cast the `NSURL`
to `CFURL`:

```
let audioURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("/path")
var audioFile : AudioFileID = nil
let status = AudioFileOpenURL(audioURL, Int8(kAudioFileReadPermission), 0, &audioFile)
```

Comment: Thank you. The error disappeared after replacing 'UnsafePointer<AudioFileID>' with 'AudioFileID'